# Can you convert HTML files to PHP without writing PHP and consequences?

Tags: php, html, performance, include

Although I can hardly write any PHP, I know the `include` functionality. I love it, since this way you can re-use your code, which with HTML you cannot (that easily). I've got a client with a website with ~ 30 pages and he has adjustments to recurring parts (i.e. header, navigation, footer, etc.) pretty often. So these adjustments I have to commit across al those pages.

To make this easier, I was thinking of changing the extension of all `.html` pages to `.php` and convert those parts to lines such as `<?php include 'navigation.php';?>` and paste the actual content in a separate file. This way I only have to adjust the separate file, instead of each page individually.

This would mean the whole site would turn into a PHP site, but consisting of 99% HTML lines and PHP Include will be the only PHP part. Will this have any consequences for it's performance, compared to 100% HTML?

**Update:** Just a thought but.. caching only caches the whole file, not parts of it. If you cache a part that gets reused and the HTML files itself get smaller (large HTML lines → `include 'header.php`), doesn't that counter the increased loading times for PHP and requests starting at the second page (since first page visit has no cache yet)?

Comment: A simple Google search could have answered this for you. In short: yes, but it will hardly be noticeable as it will be milliseconds or less.

Comment: I wouldn't say I spent hours searching, but I couldn't find anything great in the first 15 minutes of searching, actually. Just wanted some direct answers to this situation. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972002/does-php-increase-a-page-loading-time

Comment: What is the changes they make? Is it company name and email and stuff like that? If yes you can make it even easier and assign those stuff as variables and output them at the footer header and all that. So you only change the variables.php file that holds your common changed values of the page.

Comment: The most common (and annoying) thing is the navigation. Frequently pages should be added, removed, renamed, relinked and/or reordered. Other thing that can be named are social links, such as links to Facebook, Twitter and his other media accounts. Not really plain text.

Answer (score 2):

For sure it can impact performance. Serving HTML files requires only web-server (like Apache or nginx). Using PHP requires a PHP (obviously) preprocessor installed on server so it's an additional resource. For lightweight projects (like yours) it won't be any significant difference (actually insignificant).

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following to an .htaccess file which will cause all HTML pages to be processed like PHP:

```
# allows HTML files to be interpretted as PHP files
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

There should be very little, if any, performance impact and you can included PHP files in the HTML files just as you would use an include anywhere else.